# Afnetworking PUT parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, put

I'm trying to update some fields with body parametres

```
 NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/auth/password", self.baseURL ];
[[self managerWithHeaders] PUT:requestString parameters:@{@"foo":@"bar"} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task,id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task,NSError *error) {
    if(failure) failure(error, [self getErrorMessageWithCode:error.code]);
}];
```

on server this method getting

```
{"foo"=>"bar", *"password"=>{"foo"=>"bar"}}
```

But Password is a method name. Why PUT method trying update this parameters?

P.S when i send this request with string (@"%@/auth/password?foo=bar") everything is ok.

Comment: where you have used `requestString`

Comment: i'm fix mistake in code

Comment: on success block see response object , it will show actual url passed on server

Comment: I think it's because PUT request puts the parameters into the HTTPBody and not into the "URL" (as a GET method for instance). In order to make it work, you have to construct yourself that part.

Comment: can you provide some code how achieve this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments; a `PUT request` puts the parameters into the `HTTPBody` and not into the `URL` like a `GET request` would.

So, add them to your `parameters` and not to the URL part. Something like this:

```
[[self managerWithHeaders] PUT:@"example.com/auth parameters:@{@"foo":@"bar", @"password" : @"sdfsdfsff"} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task,id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task,NSError *error) {
    if(failure) failure(error, [self getErrorMessageWithCode:error.code]);
}];
```

Don't include parameters as part of the URL for `PUT requests`

Comment: Password is a method name, and i dont want change this parameter

Comment: Your code doesn't show that it's a method name. Regardless, this is how its done with AFN. My code sample is just an example on what you need to do to get it to work. Pick whatever parameter name you want -but it must go in the parameters for the request to work.